# Is there any way to have pen pressure without a tablet for photoshop CC 2014 32 bit?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I want to know is there any way to simulate pen pressure for Photoshop without a tablet? A plugin? some sort of brush? Can someone link me a tutorial or something. I just want to doodle in Photoshop. I don't want a career in graphic design.

Comment: Many ios and android drawing apps do this thing where both ends of the line are narrowed and some may even use speed. Slow = Heavy line. Fast = Thin line. This is the best you can do without actual pressure sensitivity.  I don't know if any desktop apps do this. Still, even without pressure sensitivity or any of those tricks, stylus is always better for drawing. It's like comparing drawing with a pencil and a mouse sized rock.

Comment: There are some cheap _drawing tablets_ out there, but $10 seems like asking too much.  There are some excellent bang for the buck drawing tablets, but I'd say the starting price is somewhere around $25-60. At that price pretty much any one of them is good for it. What it comes down to is small things, like: **Size.** A4 is a good size, but a5 will do in a pinch.  **Pressure levels.** Anything above 1k  should suffice even for pro's. **Tilt feature.** If that floats your boat. **Accessories.** Againt, if that's somethign that matters.

Comment: If you want a cheap tablet... you will get a cheap tablet.

Comment: Is there a way to travel 35mph without a vehicle? Sure. Is it easy, effective, reliable, and sustainable? Probably not. Photoshop has the `Fade` feature for brushes, that's about as close as you'll get. Won't read pressure but will fake variations at the ends of strokes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a presure sensitive device, the options that come to my mind are:

- A program that recognizes mouse speed. MyPaint http://mypaint.org
- Using a brush with an angle. Like a calligraphy pen.
- Using paths inside Photoshop: http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2011/05/simulating-pressure-when-stroking-a-path.html
- Some vector based programs can add a brush to a path. In ilustrator they are called Natural Media. In Corel Draw Artistic Media.